# What can I use in this program in place of break or exit? (Java)

Tags: java

I need to exit the following code without using break otherwise my professor will give me a 0.  What is the most efficient way? Sorry, I am a noob.  Please help.  Basically, he wants the program to exit logically.  Thats exactly what he said.  Also, why do people not like break?  I mean the program works perfectly with break.

```
//********Import statements*******//
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class randomNumbers  
{
   public static void main(String[] args)  
   {

    //***********Initialize variables************// 
    Random rand = new Random();   
    int[] numbers = new int[10]; //Initialize array      

    //**********************************************************************************//

    //For loop generates 10 Random Numbers in the range 1 - 23
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
    {
      //Generate random numbers between 1-23 
      int randomNum = rand.nextInt((23-1)+ 1) + 1;     

      //if number generated is less than 20
      if(randomNum < 20)   
      {
         //number generated is part of numbers to be outputted     
         numbers[i] = randomNum;      
      }

      else  //else statement, quit program as number is greater than 20
      {
         break;
      }  //end if

    }//end for loop

    //Display output
    System.out.println("Numbers Generated: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));  

    //**********************************************************************************//
   } //end main
} //end program
```

Comment: `System.exit(0)`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Comment: @bcsb1001 - may want to watch out about just dropping that anywhere, I know this example here is a stand alone app but in a web applicationor ejb application this will possibly (likely) cause the app server to shutdown [Dont use systemexit on java web application](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/11/dont-use-systemexit-on-java-web-application.html)

Comment: You're not -1'd anymore - you might remove the comment ;-)  but I agree, some people are a little mean - they could at least take the time to leave a comment as to why they're doing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of loud caps spam.

Comment: That is a lot of unnecessary code for a simple loop that creates 10 values, my advice is to rewrite the whole program; you already gave the exit condition which is i< numbers.length. you don't need the else statement and the loop terminates once you reach 10 generated values; which ends the program logically. A return statement won't work because the return type is void, which means no returned value. And why are you generating pseudo random numbers for a range you don't need? The real solution is to omit the increment in the loop declaration, and only increment when a number is stored.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the goal of the loop is to continue until a condition is met. Determine what that condition is and force the conditional to be met. In this case, make `i` equal to `numbers.length`.

**Side Note**

As Bohemian stated, `return` is another great option. This will become more relevant when methods start returning values. `Return` is a common way you will exit from methods with loops in them, unless the return type is `void`.

Comment: lol you sir are a god

Comment: @GetMoneynGirls Haha thanks. Remember to choose an answer for the question by clicking the checkmark next to the answer you choose. This will help future developers with the same question.

Comment: If you look at the method return signature 'return' does not work.

Comment: @MatthewLagerwey True. In this case return wouldn't work. I wanted to mention return in the post so the OP user could be aware of return. My solution wouldn't be ideal in every case and return is typically the way to go in those cases.

Comment: So, you're advising the OP to change the state of the loop index variable? That's usually not the safest thing to do. If he's looping an unknown number of times until a condition is met, why use a for loop with index at all?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Given the direction of the question and mentioned experience, I was trying to avoid an answer that modified the existing core code. You are right though, with a small amount of refactoring, a cleaner solution could be achieved.

Answer (score 5):

Use something like a `do...while`

```
int randomNum = ???

do {

    randomNum = ???

} while ( randomNum < 20 );

System.out.println("Random was >= 20");
```

Answer (score 4):

To exit a `void` method (*any* `void` method, including the `main()` method) use:

```
return;
```

i.e. replace `break` with `return`.

Comment: return doesnt work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition to loop. 
Create boolean property and check if you must finish loop.

```
boolean finish = false;

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length && !finish; i++) 
{
    .
    .
    .

    if(randomNum > 20){
      finish = true;
    }
}
```